# How can I get a live reload like GAE with FALCON?

Tags: python, falconframework

I am setting up a new project that is going to use python to build a RESTful back end.  I looked at GAE, but choose Falcon Framework, because the application needs to eventually be installed on local servers.   GAE has a great development feature, it allows for iterative development by watching the source, and reloading.

> You can leave the web server running while you develop your
>   application. The web server knows to watch for changes in your source
>   files and reload them if necessary.

How can I set up Falcon to do the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but I found that there is no simple method that does not require more software installed the way GAE does it, but after you install [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), your can use the --reload switch and the server will auto-reload the source.

```
$ gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -b [::1]:8000 --reload myapp:app
```

Docs: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload

Answer (score 2):

Auto-reloading is not a feature of the framework (Falcon), but rather of the server. If you do want auto-reloading, the simplest way to do it is run your Falcon code on a gunicorn server, using the `--reload` switch. For example:

```
$ gunicorn --reload app:app
```

Assuming your API is inside `app.py` and named `app`.